# Print some lines from files in a directory based on list of file names

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep

I am trying to print specific lines from a lot of files in a directory based on regular expression. I have a list of file names and a directory that contains these files. I have only been able to figure out how to print lines from ALL files in the directory. But what I need is only print lines from files that are on the filename.txt list.

```
for f in ForPAML/*.paml; do grep -m 1 'Mm10' "$f"; done
```

I used the above to print lines that have Mm10 from all files in the directory.

filename.txt looks like:

```
Mus_Rn5_.02.aa.fa.afa.paml
Mus_Rn5_.03.aa.fa.afa.paml
Mus_Rn5_.04.aa.fa.afa.paml
Mus_Rn5_.07.aa.fa.afa.paml
```

And the directory contains these files plus many more.

And the file Mus_Rn5_.03.aa.fa.afa.paml for example looks like this.

```
 2     54
Mm10-chr19:41729055-41729126
ACACTCGAAGCTGCTGGCCAGCAAAGTCATTCTTGTGGATCCGAGTGTTGTTGC
1:268429604-268429675
ACACTCGAAGCTGCTGCCCAGCAAAGTCATTCTTATGGATCCGAGTATTGTTAC
```

I need to print all lines that contain 'Mm10' along with the file name to a new file. Something like this
    `Mus_Rn5_.02.aa.fa.afa.paml`   `Mm10-chr19:41729055-41729126`
    `Mus_Rn5_.03.aa.fa.afa.paml`   `Mm10-chr11:34068938-34068969`
    `Mus_Rn5_.04.aa.fa.afa.paml`    `Mm10-chr11:34069868-34069905`

...

Also, the number of files in the directory is too many so I end up with "Argument list too long" error That is the reason I used the 'for' loop which seemed to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xargs and awk:

```
xargs -a filename.txt awk '/Mm10/ { print FILENAME, $0 }' > results.txt
```